# Android 2.3.3 emulator has no Google Services Framework installed?

Tags: android, android-emulator

There is just an Exchange account provider pre-installed in the emulator when building Android 2.3.3 from sources, although I expected better Google support (ie. Google account provider).

Where do I get the source code for "Google Services Framework"? Is it open-source at all?

Comment: Did you build the virtual device from the Google API's source or what? I'm not really sure what comes preinstalled on the emulator though.

Comment: The emulator has never come with it. You might be able to copy it from a live phone or look at how custom roms provide it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check that you've installed "Google APIs by Google Inc." for that version of Android in the SDK Manager.

Then create your avd using Google API for that version rather than just the vanilla copy.